# Why is the lexsort warning thrown for some levels of pandas DataFrames but not others?

Tags: python, pandas

**BACKGROUND**

Consider the MultiIndexed pandas DataFrame from the following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 3
rangeN = list(range(1, N + 1))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [rangeN, rangeN], names=["level1", "level2"]
)
columns = [
    (
        "col_B",
        "col_B.1",
    ),
    (
        "col_B",
        "col_B.2",
    ),
]
components = range(1, 3)
columns += [("col_A", "col_A.1", f"col_A.1.{c}") for c in components]
columns += [("col_A", "col_A.2", f"col_A.2.{c}") for c in components]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(9, 6)), columns=columns, index=index)

# df.loc[:, ("col_B", "col_B.2",)] = 7  # Warning
# df.loc[:, ("col_B", "col_B.2", slice(None))] = 7  # No warning

print("The whole df:\n", df)  # No warning
print("A subset of the df:\n", df.loc[:, ("col_A")]) # No warning
print("A subsubset of the df:\n", df.loc[:, ("col_A", "col_A.1")]) # Warning
```

which returns

```
The whole df:
                 col_B             col_A                              
              col_B.1 col_B.2   col_A.1             col_A.2          
                  NaN     NaN col_A.1.1 col_A.1.2 col_A.2.1 col_A.2.2
level1 level2                                                        
1      1            8       3         4         7         2         5
       2            3       4         1         5         7         7
       3            7       1         0         8         1         0
2      1            2       3         8         2         7         3
       2            4       4         2         5         1         5
       3            1       3         5         4         0         1
3      1            5       5         0         4         4         2
       2            4       6         8         4         6         8
       3            5       7         7         5         2         3
A subset of the df:
                 col_A.1             col_A.2          
              col_A.1.1 col_A.1.2 col_A.2.1 col_A.2.2
level1 level2                                        
1      1              4         7         2         5
       2              1         5         7         7
       3              0         8         1         0
2      1              8         2         7         3
       2              2         5         1         5
       3              5         4         0         1
3      1              0         4         4         2
       2              8         4         6         8
       3              7         5         2         3
A subsubset of the df:
                col_A.1.1  col_A.1.2
level1 level2                      
1      1               4          7
       2               1          5
       3               0          8
2      1               8          2
       2               2          5
       3               5          4
3      1               0          4
       2               8          4
       3               7          5
c:\users\tfovid\draft.py:30: PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance.
  print("A subsubset of the df:\n", df.loc[:, ("col_A", "col_A.1")]) # Warning
```

**QUESTION**

Why is indexing the higher level `df.loc[:, ("col_A")]` working fine while `df.loc[:, ("col_A", "col_A.1")]` throws a warning? I don't want to sort the array because of the current order of the columns is a requirement from the end user. Is there any way to get rid of this warning without sorting? If not, is there at least a hack (e.g., temporary sorting and then reverting back to the original column order) so that I get rid of this pesky warning?

Answer (score 0):

1. `warnings` module
   You can use the `warnings` module to filter out unwanted warnings. A common
   pattern for this is to use the `warnings.catch_warnings` context manager in
   addition to `warnings.simplefilter` to ignore any warnings inside of the
   context block.

```py
# ① Temporarily catch and ignore warnings
from warnings import catch_warnings, simplefilter
with catch_warnings():
    simplefilter('ignore')
    df.loc[:, ("col_A", "col_A.1")] = -1

print(df)
#                 col_B             col_A
#               col_B.1 col_B.2   col_A.1             col_A.2
#                   NaN     NaN col_A.1.1 col_A.1.2 col_A.2.1 col_A.2.2
# level1 level2
# 1      1            7       1        -1        -1         7         4
#        2            5       5        -1        -1         6         0
#        3            2       4        -1        -1         3         6
# 2      1            4       1        -1        -1         5         1
#        2            7       3        -1        -1         2         7
#        3            1       5        -1        -1         7         3
# 3      1            8       2        -1        -1         7         7
#        2            3       8        -1        -1         3         2
#        3            0       1        -1        -1         5         8
```

2. sort, do work, unsort.

This pattern speaks for itself, you can sort your columns to do whatever you
need to do. Then reselect the original column ordering when you’re done.

```py
# ② Temporarily sort and reindex to original ordering
tmp_df = df.sort_index(axis='columns')
tmp_df.loc[:, ("col_A", "col_A.1")] = -1
df = tmp_df[df.columns] # “unsort” the tmp_df
# df.update(tmp_df) # alternatively

print(df)
#                 col_B             col_A
#               col_B.1 col_B.2   col_A.1             col_A.2
#                   NaN     NaN col_A.1.1 col_A.1.2 col_A.2.1 col_A.2.2
# level1 level2
# 1      1            3       0        -1        -1         2         5
#        2            5       4        -1        -1         1         1
#        3            7       5        -1        -1         3         7
# 2      1            3       3        -1        -1         1         2
#        2            0       6        -1        -1         7         1
#        3            3       4        -1        -1         0         2
# 3      1            3       1        -1        -1         8         2
#        2            0       0        -1        -1         5         5
#        3            6       2        -1        -1         0         8
```